# Want to animate characters in android

Tags: android

I am working on sms application and I want to use animated characters who will read sms.
I am new to android can anyone please let me know how to do it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't enough information here to even begin an answer.  What do you mean `animated characters who will read SMS`?

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you a brief outline as the scope of the question is very broad:

The simplest way could be to use Frame Anmation for your animated characters . Each frame wll contain a diiferent character animation so that you play it frame-by-frame.
To read sms aloud.. use TTS(Test To Speech) feature of android. 
Finally, Register a broadcast receiver to listen to incoming sms.

Comment: Thanks but I have used text to speech and it is reading sms with the female voice but now I want to use different funny characters and want to animate their mouth movement as per sms text. so would please give me any suggestions regarding this application ? thanks once again in advance